# Is it secure not to set a user in django admin?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible for someone to hack into my django admin app, if I do not create a user for it, by executing:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

For example, is there a default username-password pair that someone could use to gain access to django admin?

Comment: Django's code is open source, and you presumably have access to the database it is using. There is also documentation. Have you checked in those places?

Comment: You are right, I could have checked the source code. But for someone wandering about the same thing as me, why does he/she have to go under the same process and not spent much less time, reading an answer on this website. After all, this is why stackexchanges websites are for :-) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Is it possible to login with default credentials

There is no default user, and [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-createsuperuser-username) state:

> The username and email address for the new account can be supplied by using the --username and --email arguments on the command line. If either of those is not supplied, createsuperuser will prompt for it when running interactively.

As such there is no default user that you could login with.

## If someone can execute arbitrary commands, could I be hacked

Yes, if someone can run the create user command they can make a new admin user and use it, but they could also run any command they like, so at that point you have already lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question boils down to this, right?

> is there a default username-password pair

If so, the answer is "no."  Here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) for `createsuperuser`

Of course, you need to also be vigilant about the general security considerations of your web app, including authentication issues not directly related to the presence or absence of a default user.

[This](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is another great resource I suggest you look at.